# UINavController whiting another UINavController

Tags: xcode

Hi I am new to Xcode/objective c and I need some help.
My application has multiple views and more views within a view

Main View is managing my view 1, 2, 3 & 4 via UINavigationController (segmented switch) no problem there. my problem arises when I am trying to load my View 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc.

Yes I have a View1, and 4 more views in it 1.1, 1.2, 1.3,  1.4.
Same for the others Views,  View 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 & 2.4.
Changing between views 1, 2, 3 & 4 is no problem.
The approach I am taking to load view 1.1 etc  Is to ad another UINavigationController in View 1 and use a tab bar items to switch between my views 1.1, 1.2 etc.
Is this correct or you can not load a UINavController whiting another UINavController.
I been unsuccessful  so far.

Thank You for your help in advanced.

Comment: Hey! If my answer was helpful, please accept it. Otherwise, please provide further information.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't fully understand your setup. Still, I guess I can answer your question: No, it is not possible to have a `UINavigationController` within a `UINavigationController`. Please have a look at the '[View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)', [this section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1) describes how ViewControllers can be combined.

If you need multiple `UINavigationController` in your app, you should probably separate them in a `UITabBarController` or by using `presentModalViewController`.